# Can I increase number value for each new user in sqlite3 database use golang?

Tags: database, go, sqlite

I ask is possible to increase id number per new user in sqlite3 database using golang and xorm without cause async problem?

- I will use golang for http server. So may many user in same time http request and register

For example this is my database

```
sid int
username string
password string
```

Now the question is for example I have 5 user before that and last user sid is 5, so it is possible to increase sid number for user 6 without cause problem?

The main problem is this; In my method when new request received by server for register. Server check last sid from sqlite3 database. For example if last sid is 5 server increase this number with + 1 so our sid get 6 but when try save new user to sid 6 when server is busy and in same time another guy want register cause error to sid 6 already taken. I know this is not professional method and now try find solotion.

Comment: Is `sid` just a plain integer or do you use [`AUTOINCREMENT`](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)?

Comment: only integer number and i want it will be incorrect per new user registered

Comment: Is it the primary key of the table? Is there any constraint on in? If no, you can enter anything you want, even though this is stupid. Use the features provided by SQLite to generate IDs.

Comment: Yes this is primary key, but how it increment that number. in my older method find last sid number from database and increment + 1 but when many users request cause database error and say this sid already taken.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the relevant but complete definition of the table.

Comment: Edited you can now again check sir

Comment: Use an auto increment id. This has nothing to do with Go.

Comment: You should read https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html before using `AUTOINCREMENT` and make an informed decision about if you really need what it actually does, btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't let the server code generate the ID. Let the DB do this job. SQLite has the [`AUTOINCREMENT`](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html) keyword for this task.

**Edit:** But as the SQLite documentation cleary tells use, the use of `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` is recommended over `AUTOINCREMENT`.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, this fix my problem. I accept

Comment: Not quite. An `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`/rowid column will always have a new number assigned if one is not given on insert. The misleadingly named `AUTOINCREMENT` just changes how that number is determined (and comes with a big warning about how you probably don't want to use it). See https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Comment: @Shawn Good advice, I've changed my answer.